# Trouble using pip after installing Python 2.7 with Homebrew on Mac OS X 10.6.8

Tags: python, osx-snow-leopard, pip, homebrew

I just used homebrew to install Python 2.7.2 on a clean Mac OS X Snow Leopard install, but seem to be having trouble getting PIP to work with it well.

Here are the steps that I took:

1. Installed python with Homebrew: `brew install python --framework
   --universal`
2. Updated my paths in my `.zsrc`
3. Made a symbolic link from `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current` to `/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current`
4. Used `easy_install` to install `pip`

These steps seem like they have worked:

```
$ brew doctor
Your system is raring to brew.

$ which python
/usr/local/bin/python

$ python --version
Python 2.7.2 

$ which easy_install
/usr/local/share/python/easy_install

$ which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
```

However, when I try to install things with pip, for example `$ pip install ipython` I get this error message `'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/share': Permission denied`

Why is pip still trying to install an old Python 2.6 location? How do I get it to install things to `/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/` etc?

Comment: Does `head -1 $(which pip)` point to `/usr/local/bin/python`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it looks like the way that I installed things I needed to use `/usr/local/share/python/pip-2.7` instead of `/usr/local/share/python/pip`.

Not sure why I have both pip and pip-2.7 but Aliasing my pip to the the 2-7 version seems to fix my issue.

Answer (score 2):

Homebrewed Python now installs `pip`.

[Since a while](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/commit/2a09cbe0dcad7d310b0041c0f5f0da9adb0768d1#L0R163) pip is installed directly into your homebrew-bin directory.

Therefore, `$(brew --prefix)/bin/pip` should be in your `PATH`, if your Homebrewbrew is set up correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using `easy_install` to install pip? Based on the path easy_install is probably pointing to Python 2.6, which results to pip point to 2.6 as well.

Doesn't `brew install pip` fix this?

Otherwise what you are doing [looks correct](http://readthedocs.org/docs/clint/en/latest/installation.html)